# Get error of XSLTProcessor

Tags: javascript, xslt, error-handling

I would like to get transformation errors.

Here is my code:

```
var xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();
xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xsl);
var resultDocument = xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(xml, document);
```

I want to know when I made a typo, for example `<xsl:apply-template>` insteand of `<xsl:apply-templateS>`.

I read the doc but I didn't see anything on this part...

My browser is Chrome 26.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created http://jsfiddle.net/cDug4/1/ to test whether the browser throws an exception on `importStylesheet` if the DOM tree of the stylesheet code has been parsed successfully as XML but is not a valid stylesheet.

Firefox and Opera throw an exception, Opera even a nice one saying "XSLT_PARSING_FAILED_ERR: Error: unrecognized element in the XSLT namespace" but Chrome does not throw an exception it seems.

Comment: Ok thanks, but the errors given by FF and Opera are not very helpful... A line number would be much better!

Comment: charles, I agree a line numbers are helpful. But I am not sure they exist in the DOM tree that `importStylesheet` takes as an argument.